# Unable to read array after eval(responseText) + Javascript + JSON + Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I pass activerecord data from rails to JavaScript function as JSON using ajax.
my request.responseText looks like this

```
[{"site": {"lng": 55.1443, "lat": 25.0608}},
 {"site": {"lng": 55.1065, "lat": 25.0399}}]
```

Below is my JavaScript code

```
var sites=eval('(' + request.responseText + ')');

for (var i = 0 ; i < sites.length ; i++) {
      var site=sites[i].attributes
      var lat=site.lat;
      var lng=site.lng;
```

but if I `alert(site.lat)` it's returning `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

```
 var site=sites[i].attributes
```

should be

```
 var site=sites[i].site
```

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks a lot. I was breaking my head over this. Newbie problems :)

Comment: You're welcome :) And since you're new to the site - it's customary to mark the answer that helped you achieve your goal ;)